# Autocad files (.dwg,.dxf,.dwf etc) upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dwg

I added this line in `./system/application/config/mimes.php`

```
'dwg' => array('application/acad', 'application/x-acad', 'application/autocad_dwg', 'image/x-dwg', 'application/dwg', 'application/x-dwg', 'application/x-autocad', 'image/vnd.dwg', 'drawing/dwg'),
```

I tried to upload a **.dwg** file but it shows an error like this:

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

How can I upload a **.dwg** file?

Answer (score 2):

The file extension `dwg` must be in your `allowed_types`:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'dwg';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

If you want to allow multiple types, they must be pipe `|` delimited:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'dwg|dxf|dwf';
```

Reference: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Although it appears to be undocumented in the current user guide, using an asterisk `*` will allow all types:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
```

Comment: i have already done all the things you mentioned above; Oh and i tried `$config['allowed_types'] = '*';` as well. But it still didn't help me out :(

Comment: Can you post your actual code with the upload config and an example file name if possible? Have you made sure you can upload other file types?

Comment: Config: `$config['file_name']   = date('YmdHis').'_'.rand(0,9).'.'.$this->getFileExt($fieldName);
   $config['upload_path']   = realpath('./uploads/client/bi/');
   $config['allowed_types']  = 'dxf|dwg|dwf|gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
   $config['max_size']   = '2000';`
    and i have changed the mime setting by adding following lines; `'dwf'   => array('drawing/x-dwf', 'model/vnd.dwf'),'dwg'   => array('application/acad', 'image/vnd.dwg', 'image/x-dwg'),
    'dxf'   => array('application/dxf', 'image/vnd.dwg', 'image/x-dwg')`.Now it uploads images perfectly but shows error while trying autocad files.

Comment: and i am using this file for test: http://download.autodesk.com/us/samplefiles/acad/visualization_-_aerial.dwg

Comment: Those mime types simply didn't work for me. I used `application/octet-stream` and tried, it worked ! I solved the problem but still wondering why those mime types didn't work?!

Comment: @AnilSharma: If that was the solution, post your own answer. After a couple days, you can accept it. This will help people having the same problem.

Comment: What do you mean? It's not allowing you to post your own answer?

Comment: It has just allowed ! I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution :**

Those mime types simply didn't work for me. I just used `application/octet-stream` and tried, it worked ! I solved the problem but still wondering why those mime types didn't work? !

Comment: For those reading this years later:- this answer is highly unrecommended. `application/octet-stream` is the mime type equivalent of 'miscellaneous', therefore the server could still be tricked into running malicious code (e.g. an exe)

Please see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#File_uploads to gain more of an insight.

Comment: I agree with u. It was a question from almost 5 years ago while I was facing this issue for the first time. Anyways, thanks for the reply.